# Flutter BlocBuilder is not called for new states

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

My bloc is yielding new states e.g. like this:

```
yield Loaded();
yield Loaded();
```

My BlocListener retrieves both of these, even though they are the same.

My BlocBuilder on the other hand does not. It will only retrieve the first (or last?) one.

I'm not using equatable and I don't understand why BlocBuilder wont be triggered both times.

In my case I simply want to update the UI again without actually changing the state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building widgets is an expensive task and Flutter tries to minimize this cost wherever possible. One of them is preventing repetitive building when state changes. Here is an example:

```
class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  int a = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(a);
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
        setState(() => a = 1);
        setState(() => a = 1);
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

This example prints 0 at the first build. After clicking on the button you should expect 2 prints with value of 1 but you will get only one message in the console. Because `setState` does not immediately cause a rebuild. `setState` will immediately call the closure passed to it and then marks your widget as dirty (to get rebuild in the next frame). That's why calling `setState` multiple times fires `build` method of your widget only once. Now if you change the last `setState` in that code to `setState(() => a = 2)` you will get 2 in the console after clicking on button. If you reverse them (set a to be 2 at first and then 1) you will get 1 in the console. Now with that in mind let's see how `BlocBuilder` works?

`BlocBuilder` is a `StatefulWidget` and uses `BlocListener` to update it's state and rebuild the widgets if needed. Here is it's `build` method:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return BlocListener<C, S>(
    cubit: _cubit,
    listenWhen: widget.buildWhen,
    listener: (context, state) => setState(() => _state = state),
    child: widget.build(context, _state),
  );
}
```

As you can see the same behavior we saw in our example applies here too and if you yield multiple states repetitively in a short time, It will get built once with the latest state.

Comment: Good explanation, it makes sense now. Meanwhile I have found a workaround for my problem so I don't have to do it this way anymore. I still wonder though if I can somehow force the state to be consumed immediately and not be batched together, even if called in a very short time. The only way I can think of now is to use BlocListener in your widget and call setState inside of it in case of the desired state change, as BlocListener won't batch them together.

Comment: The only way to achieve this behavior, is making a delay between your two yields but I think there is something wrong with the way you want to solve your problem @Bonsai

Comment: My original problem was that I had a page with some textfields and a list of pictures, loaded seperatly (as the pictures might take long). After the texts finished loading, I yielded the "Loaded" state and after the pictures were done loading I yielded the "Loaded" state again but noticed it won't trigger my BlocBuilder again so the pictures didn't become visible.

Comment: You can ask it as a new question with more details and code. I will check it @Bonsai